# Consume JSON messages using KAFKA REST API

Tags: rest, apache-kafka

I have a requirement where messages are coming in json format from ACTIVEMQ and I have to expose end point where I can receive messages. I am using KAFKA but don't know whether can I use KAFKA REST API to receive json messages and store them against a particular topic in Kafka broker?

Answer (score 0):

There is no REST API in the core Apache Kafka distribution but there is a very good open source REST Proxy for Kafka available from Confluent. It enables both publish and subscribe via REST APIs. The code and docs are on github at https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest or you can download the entire Confluent open source platform which includes Apache Kafka, REST Proxy, Schema Registry and a few other useful enhancements at http://www.confluent.io/download/